# Mostrar información de un array php en formulario con inputs html

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo esta consulta que me muestra los resultados en un array, quiero mostrar la información de este array en un formulario con inputs. Gracias

```
$sentencia=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id=:id");

$sentencia->bindParam(':id',$id);
$sentencia->execute();
$listaUsuarios2=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($listaUsuarios2);
```

El formulario lo muestro en un modal e intente mostrar los datos con un foreach, pero no funciona, muestra el ultimo array que selecciono y así se queda, no cambia.
Código html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" id="modal2">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modal3" style="background-color:#f2e7e6;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Modifique sus datos:</h2>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" name="accion" value="Cancelar">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </div>          
                <div class="modal-body" >
                    <?php foreach($listaUsuarios2 as $usuario2){ ?>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $usuario2['nombre']; ?>">
                            <input type="email" name="correo" value="<?php echo $usuario2['correo']; ?>">
                            <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $usuario2['pass']; ?>">
                            <input type="number" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $usuario2['telefono']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="carrera" value="<?php echo $usuario2['carrera']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="curp" value="<?php echo $usuario2['curp']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="genero" value="<?php echo $usuario2['genero']; ?>">
                            <input type="date" name="fechanac" value="<?php echo $usuario2['fechanac']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="estado" value="<?php echo $usuario2['estado']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="municipio" value="<?php echo $usuario2['municipio']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="localidad" value="<?php echo $usuario2['localidad']; ?>">

                            <button value="Enviar" type="submit" name="accion">Enviar</button>
                        </form>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btn">Salir</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Agrega como texto la salida que te va `print_r($listaUsuarios2);` además comparte por favor que has intentado

Comment: Puedes recorrer `$listaUsuarios2` con un bucle y dentro construir los `inputs` que quieres y sus valores, algo así: `foreach ($$listaUsuarios2 as $row) { //aquí desgranas cada columna/valor que haya en los resultados }` cabe decir que, podrías recurrir a ciertas estrategias como por ejemplo usar el nombre de columna para la etiqueta `name` de los `input`... Sea como sea, faltan detalles en la pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor, pon un ejemplo mínimo del tipo de salida que quieres y explica si necesitas mostrar los `input` *in situ*  o en otra parte.

Comment: Ya lo intente, como lo acabo de mostrar, pero siempre se queda con el primer seleccionado, no cambia, ni actualizando.

Comment: Como lo estás haciendo a lo sumo te creará tantos formularios como registros haya. Si quieres un sólo formulario y dentro `inputs` con cada fila de los resultados, tienes que crear el `form` fuera del `foreach`, luego, dentro del `foreach` creas los `input` y al final del `foreach` terminas de completar el formulario.